# Redirect to Controller action from an Async Controller action not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asynchronous

I'm having a problem redirecting from this controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginBindingModel model, string returnUrl)
```

using

```
if (loginViewModel.IsConfirmed)
            {
                await accountService.AuditLogin().ConfigureAwait(false);
                user = await usersService.GetUser().ConfigureAwait(false);

                await SessionWrapper.SetCurrentApplicationUserAsync(user.Data).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await SessionWrapper.SetIsAuthenticatedAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);

                **return RedirectToAction("Index", "Fixtures");**
            }
```

Nothing happens, it just redirects back to the same page. I've had an extensive look around, but information I have found hasn't helped.

The controller action I am redirecting to looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(){...}
```

I have a feeling that it's got something to do with the fact that it's an async method, but i don't understand enough about it to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this was all my doing!

I completely overlooked the obvious. I'm now saving my session in Redis cache because I was having issues accessing and setting is asynchronously, however forgot to change my session checkers that redirected me back to login.

Once I changed those, I was able to move past the login page.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 0):

if both methods are in the same controller then instead of **return RedirectToAction("Index", "Fixtures");**

write  "return RedirectToAction("Index");"

if they aren't in the same controller then

write "return RedirectToAction("Index", "name of the controller where your method is");"

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I dont see how that is any different to what I have already with the line : return RedirectToAction("Index", "Fixtures") - Fixtures being the name of the controller